# Why this code that I literally copied from my online class doesn't work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why this code doesn't work? I'm doing an online course for python beginners and I literally copied the code from the professor. In addition, if I run this code throughout their own app for coding for exams, the code works. Only give me problems in Atom.

The code is:

```
sh = input("Hours: ")
sr = input("Rate: ")
try:
    fh = float(sh)
    fr = float(sr)
except:
    print("Error, please enter numeric input")
    quit()

print(fh, fr)
if fh > 40 :
    reg = fr * fh
    otp = (fh - 40.0) * (fr * 0.5)
    xp = reg + otp
else:
    xp = fh * fr
print("Pay: ", xp)
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "copia_2.py", line 2, in <module>
sr = input("Rate: ")
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'e' is not defined
```

Thanks

Comment: Works just fine on my end.

Comment: Are you using python 2?

Comment: Don't use Python 2

Comment: Be sure to use python 3. If you need to use python 2 instead then use raw_input() instead of input().

Answer (score 0):

I believe you got that error when testing out the `try` `except` block.

The error happens when you input a character into the input statement if you are using python2.

You see, in python2, `input()` is the equivalent of `eval(input())` in python3.

So you inputting `'e'` is the same as referencing the variable `e`, which you haven't defined.

Use `raw_inut()` to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you trying to run it with python2. If so - try to run it under python
To find out what exact version you using at the moment - enter python interpreter and 1) `import sys` 2) `print(sys.executable)`